# llvm cannot iterate a [3 x i8]

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to "parse" a part of LLVM IR. More exactly, from

```
@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8] c"DS\00", section "llvm.metadata"
```

I want to get "DS". It is the single place in the whole bytecode from where I can get it. I have :

```
...
Value *VV = cast<Value>(LD100->getOperand(1)->getOperand(0));
errs()<<"\n VV  "<<*(VV)<<"\n";
RESULT : VV  @.str = private unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8] c"DS\00", section "llvm.metadata"

if(VV->getValueID() == Value::GlobalVariableVal){
    GlobalVariable* FD = cast<GlobalVariable>(VV);
    Value *VVV = cast<Value>(FD->getOperand(0));
    errs()<<"\n VVV  "<<*(VVV)<<"\n";
    RESULT :  VVV  [3 x i8] c"DS\00"

    if(VVV->getValueID() == Value::ConstantDataArrayVal){
        ConstantArray *caa = (ConstantArray *)VVV;
        errs()<<"\n "<<(caa->getNumOperands())<<"\n";
        errs()<<"\n "<<*(caa->getType())<<"\n";
        RESULT :  0
                  [3 x i8]
    }
```

From this point, I tried to cast to every `enum llvm::Value::ValueTy` in order to try to iterate through [3 X i8], in order to get "DS" (as a StringRef or std::string would be nice), but I cannot. How I can parse this structure?

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by converting caa to `ConstantDataArray` and then use `getAsString()` that gives me exactly "DS".